# Meraki VPN behind NAT breaks Bitbucket Git on WSL2 (Ubuntu 20) on Windows 10

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, git, windows-10, bitbucket

I access two Meraki VPNs from my Windows 10 Pro (10.0.19042 Build 19042) machine:

- One which is not behind a NAT - when I switch this on, I can do `git clone [...]` or `git fetch [...]` just fine.
- Second, which is behind
  a NAT - when I switch that on and run `git fetch`, I am geting error message: "**fatal:
  unable to access 'https://bitbucket.org/[project]/[project-name].git/':
  gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the pull function.**"

To make the second VPN work, I've executed following commands in the PowerShell:

- `Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\PolicyAgent" -Name "AssumeUDPEncapsulationContextOnSendRule" -Type DWORD -Value 2 –Force;`
- `reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Rasman\Parameters" /v AllowL2TPWeakCrypto /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f`
- `reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Rasman\Parameters" /v ProhibitIpSec /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f`

It was also necessary to disable IPv6.

That made the VPN work for Windows, but not for Linux inside WSL2. Any suggestions? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

The problem was in a mismatch between VPN MTU and Linux under WSL2 MTU sizes.

It can be identified via 2 commands:

**Windows PowerShell (run as administrator)**

`netsh interface ipv4 show subinterfaces`

Notice the first row - it shows how big MTU is allowed in your VPN.

**Linux (inside WSL2) console**

`ip addr`

Notice the row starting 'eth0' - its MTU must match or be lower that the one above.

In my case the MTU in Linux was higher.

**Solution**

The following command instantly solves the problem:

`sudo ip link set dev eth0 mtu 1400` (update MTU value to fit your VPN)

I have put it inside my `~/.bashrc` and put `/usr/sbin/ip` into sudoers NOPASSWD for my account.

**Better solution**

So far I haven't managed to use any of the standard Linux tools to change MTU on Linux startup inside WSL2 (and hence to avoid putting it into .bashrc).

- `rc-local` doesn't work under WSL2
- `/etc/dhcp/dhcpclient.conf` doesn't
  propagate changes into `default interface-mtu` nor `supersede interface-mtu`
- `netsh interface ipv4 set subinterface "vEthernet (WSL)" mtu=1400 store=persistent` doesn't affect Linux
- `/etc/netplan`
  doesn't run inside WSL2

If you find the way, I'd be more than happy to have it here!

Comment: I found this helpful implementing this solution https://askubuntu.com/questions/216804/want-to-execute-sudo-command-on-shell-startup

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I think you need to allow an extra 28 bits to be eaten on top of the VPN MTU, so make the MTU 28 lower than the VPN's MTU.

Answer (score 0):

**My solution here was:**

```
sudo ip link set dev eth0 mtu 1350
```

**NOT:**

```
sudo ip link set dev eth0 mtu 1400
```

Test it by lowering the MTU value to adapt to your network settings.